# Removing Unused dependencies from React project

Tags: npm, node-modules, npm-install

I'm currently working on a Reactjs project and i was asked to list and remove all unused dependencies. so i ran `npx depcheck` that gave me a list of all the unused. Since there is alot of unused dep i tried to remove them quickly by deleting them from the `package.json`, deleting the node modules and running `npm install`, but this solution gave me an error. i would like to understand if this way is correct or should i run `npm uninstall` for every dependency? is there a quicker way of doing it?

Comment: It sounds like depcheck is giving you some false positives. If you check their project on github there are quite a few reports about it. https://github.com/depcheck/depcheck/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+false You could use that list to remove things one by one though and see which break the build instead of removing them all at once.

Comment: is removing all of them from the package.json and doing an npm install correct globally?(not in my case),otherwise the list is pretty long is there a quicker way? thank you

Comment: Yes that should have worked if the packages weren't really used. There are script-hooks for when installing packages but that isn't available when uninstalling so you shouldn't have missed anything that way.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use **depcheck** to track dependencies, by installing it globally(using command -g) 
   Or
2. you can track dependencies using **npm-check**

Then you can uninstall unused dependencies using commands

> npm uninstall <package_name>

> npm uninstall --save <package_name>

(replace <package_name> by package name. 
eg. npm uninstall react-bootstrap)

You can refer to dependencies tracking and unistallation related blog [here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-remove-unused-dependencies-in-react)

Comment: eg. npm uninstall react-router-dom

Comment: You can also specify version name. eg. npm uninstall react@2.7.1